# iOS two UITableViews on storyboard how to handle

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard, ios5

In my iPad app storyboard design, there are two table views added.

One table view is for **displaying the folder names** and the other table view is for **displaying the file names**. When ever a folder table view cell is selected the files inside the selected folder needs to to be displayed in the other table view(the files table view).

**My problem is**

I am confused about

- How to add delegate and data source for each table view in `ViewController` ? or is it possible to add data source and delegates for each table view in a custom class other than ViewController ?

**and**

- How to handle the selection of cell ?

Please help !

Comment: Yes you can add different data source for different tableViews just define the `IBOutlate` for each table view you can bifurcate the tabelViews with their `tab` property as per my knowledge this will work

Comment: can you please tell me how to define IBOutlate for each table view. After I have set IBOutlate, should I crete an instance of the table views and add it on the view controller ?

Comment: just see the answer below this shows what I have said in above comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: Why don't you just display the files on a pushed viewController which takes up the whole screen? Seems more intuitive for me.

If you want to do it with two tableViews, and assuming they use dynamic cells than:
**1,** In the **.h file of your view controller**

specify two tableView properties like so:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *foldersTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *filesTableView;
```

implement the two delegate protocols of the UITableVIew

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

**2,** Add the two UITableViews onto your ViewController, and...

- ...link your Outlets to the two tableviews
- ...on the attributes inspector set the Tag of the foldersTableView to 1 and the filesTableView to 2
- ...select each of the UITableViews, go to the Connections Inspector and link their two delegate methods (delegate and datasource) to your ViewController (for both of them)

**3,** In the .m file of your ViewController implement the three datasource methods of UITableView like so:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
       return theNumberOfSectionsYouWantForTheFolderTableView;
    } else {
       return theNumberOfSectionsYouWantForTheFilesTableView;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
       return [foldersArray count];
    } else {
       return [filesArray count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;

} else {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
}
```

**4,** Implement the selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        //fill filesArray with the objects you want to display in the filesTableView...
        [filesTableView reloaddata];
    } else {
        //do something with the selected file
    }
}
```

Hope I got everything correctly. Don't forget to `@synthesize` the properties in the .m file if you are using pre XCode 4.4.

Comment: It should be (tableview.tag == 1) not (tableview.tag = 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple tables, don't forget to hide as appropriate:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.table2 setHidden:YES];
    [self.table1 setHidden:NO];
    // Probably reverse these in didSelectRow
}
```